# Git mergetool using Android Studio (IntelliJ)

Tags: git, android-studio, intellij-idea, git-merge, mergetool

I am trying to use Android Studio as my git mergetool in Windows. I followed the instructions on official [IntelliJ documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/running-intellij-idea-as-a-diff-or-merge-command-line-tool.html#d622577e199). Yet, when I try to do the merge, Android Studio launches with the following error:

> Error showing merge: The system cannot find the path specified

Here is my .gitconfig setup:

```
[merge]
      tool = androidstudio 
[mergetool]
      prompt = false
[mergetool "androidstudio"]
      cmd = cmd.exe //c "\"C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/bin/studio64.exe\" merge \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\" \"$BASE\" \"$MERGED\""
      keepbackup = false
      trustexitcode = true
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have worked. It shows an error in the command line that there was a merge issue but it does open the Android Studio merge tool and prompts you to go through the merge.

```
[merge]
      tool = androidstudio
[mergetool]
      prompt = false
[mergetool "androidstudio"]
      cmd = '"C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/bin/studio64.exe"' merge $LOCAL $REMOTE $BASE $MERGED
      keepbackup = false
      trustexitcode = true
```